# MS Access Formula to Update one field in a table based on the amount "between" two other fields

Tags: ms-access, formula, between

I'm hoping someone can help me out.  I was hoping I could do an update query in MS Access that will update a field I have called "Materiality by Fiscal Year", based on whether or not another field "Brand Savings" is equal to or between a set of dollar ranges I have in another table.  The first table is as follows, which is the primary table:

```
+----------+------------+---------------+----------------------------+
|  Brand   | Project ID | Brand Savings | Materiality by Fiscal Year |
+----------+------------+---------------+----------------------------+
| aBS Corp |        121 | $110,000.00   |                            |
| aBS Corp |        151 | $17,640.67    |                            |
| aBS Corp |        152 | $5,682.37     |                            |
| aBS Corp |        154 | $564,669.58   |                            |
| aBS Corp |        157 | $5,097.00     |                            |
| aBS Corp |        159 | $33,798.00    |                            |
| aBS Corp |        190 | $200,000.00   |                            |
| aBS Corp |        193 | $250,000.00   |                            |
| aBS Corp |        194 | $366,666.67   |                            |
| aBS Corp |        197 | $90,799.00    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         20 | $14,000.00    |                            |
| aBS Corp |        219 | $2,800.00     |                            |
| aBS Corp |        222 | $132.58       |                            |
| aBS Corp |         23 | $2,068.30     |                            |
| aBS Corp |        233 | $32,908.60    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         25 | $9,143.18     |                            |
| aBS Corp |         34 | $11,674.85    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         35 | $11,615.60    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         36 | $14,959.28    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         39 | $35,000.00    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         40 | $100,000.00   |                            |
| aBS Corp |         60 | $55,000.00    |                            |
| aBS Corp |         61 | $250,094.72   |                            |
| aBS Corp |         64 | $925,000.00   |                            |
| aBS Corp |         69 | $400,000.00   |                            |
| aBS Corp |         75 | $14,625.00    |                            |
+----------+------------+---------------+----------------------------+
```

The second table is a reference table:

```
+------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+
| FiscalYear |     Low Range     |     High Range     |     Result     |
+------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+
|       2016 |  (100,000,000.00) |         24,999.00  | 0-24.9K        |
|       2016 |  25,000.00        |         49,999.00  | 25-49.9K       |
|       2016 |  50,000.00        |         99,999.00  | 50-99.9K       |
|       2016 |  100,000.00       |  1,000,000,000.00  | 100K or Higher |
+------------+-------------------+--------------------+----------------+
```

I was hoping to be able to reference the 2nd table in order to update the "Materiality by  fiscal Year" field based on whether or not the value in "Brand Savings" is BETWEEN the "Low Range" and "High Range" fields.  I couldn't figure it out however, and it's driving me crazy.  Instead, I have 4 different queries that will update the "Materiality by Fiscal Year" field (an example of the formula used in the query is below:)

**IIf(([Brand Savings]>=0) And ([Brand Savings]<=24999),"$0-24.9K")**

Basically what I'm asking is whether or not there's a formula I can use to reference the "Low range" and "High range" fields in the reference table to determine if the "Brand Savings" value from the main table is BETWEEN those two amounts, and if so, populate the "Materiality by Fiscal Year" field with the "Result" field from the Reference table?

Sorry, that's kind of "wordy", just don't know how else to explain it.

Thanks all!

Comment: Please don't post images of your tables. Instead, see [How to share a table for MS Access](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359195/share-a-table-on-stack-overflow-for-easy-import-into-ms-access)

Comment: Just updated based on your comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `DLookUp` in your update query to look up the appropriate value:

`DLookUp("Result", "SecondTable", CDbl([Brand Savings]) & " Between [Low Range] And [High Range]")`

For `SELECT` queries, you could also use a join, but I doubt if that would work in an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted. See [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information on accepting answers, and what to do.

Comment: I think I "accepted" it correctly.  If not, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, thank you. You may notice you've gained 2 rep by accepting the answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the table with the Brand Savings is called tblBrandSavings and the table with the ranges is called tblRanges.
Then you could use this UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE tblBrandSavings, tblRanges
SET [Materiality by Fiscal Year] = tblRanges.Result 
WHERE  tblBrandSavings.[Brand Savings] BETWEEN tblRanges.[Low Range] AND tblRanges.[High Range];
```

The question is why you would run to store the same date in multiple tables.
I'd suggest a simple SELECT statement:

```
SELECT tblBrandSavings.Brand, tblBrandSavings.[Project ID], tblBrandSavings.[Brand Savings], ( 
SELECT tblRanges.Result 
FROM tblRanges 
WHERE  tblBrandSavings.[Brand Savings] BETWEEN tblRanges.[Low Range] AND tblRanges.[High Range]
 ) AS [Materiality by Fiscal Year]
FROM tblBrandSavings;
```